# why outer for loop variable can't be used in inner for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am writing following code:

```
int j =0;
for( j=0; j< 10;j++){
  System.out.println("Printing outer for loop :" +j);
  for(j; j < 8; j++)
  {
     System.out.println("Printing inner for loop" + j);
  }
}
```

Eclipse showing me following error:

```
Syntax error on token "j", ++ expected after this token
```

I don't understand the reason behind. Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `j;` to do? If you don't want to assign an initial value to `j`, just write `for(; j < 8; j++)`

Comment: Reason is, you have a invalid `for` loop syntax, `for(j; j < 8; j++)`is not a valid for loop.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the down votes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1), the first "part" of the `for` loop declaration, `ForInit`, is a [list of statement expressions or a local variable declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8); `j` isn't a statement expression (an assignment; a pre/post increment/decrement; a method invocation; a new class initialization) or a local variable declaration, so it's invalid syntax.

Depending upon what you are trying to do, you can just omit it:

```
for (; j < 8; j++)
```

Note that all of the three "parts" of the `for` loop are optional: for instance, this is fine:

```
for (;;) {
}
```

(It's just an infinite loop)

Answer (score 2):

`j;` is not a valid statement, which is why your inner loop does not compile. You don't need to put a statement in there, you can just leave the "first part" empty in the inner loop:

```
int j =0;
for( j=0; j< 10;j++){
    System.out.println("Printing outer for loop :" +j);
    for(; j < 8; j++)
    {
        System.out.println("Printing inner for loop" + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the for loop is initialisation statement - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

```
for (initialisation; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

> for(j; j < 8; j++)

Please initialise the first statement in the above for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Loops are not isolated like a function.